# How to store access logs in one LOG STREAM instead of numerous?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

In API gateway, access logging lets you define only up to a log group but not the log stream for the incoming logs.

How can I override this? I suspect it would be through IAM policies but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to do this.

The multiple log streams are there for scalability.

A single CloudWatch Log Stream can only accept  [5 `PutLogEvents` requests of up to 1 MB each, per second](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/cloudwatch_limits_cwl.html), so a single log stream would not be sufficient at any kind of scale.

Comment: Thank you. I read something similar but was under the impression that I must have missed something.